# Xamarin Android Designer Not Working

Tags: xamarin

My Android Designer isn't working in vs2015. I have installed even the latest updates but it isn't working still.
I'm getting the error message in the following picture:

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDK Manager can be ran manually from:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\SDK Manager.exe"

Please also check that you have installed proper SDK - you'll need one of latest - 25 and one of you need (like 17 or so)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right there. Install an Android SDK, and in Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android, tell it where you installed it.